# Full desktop experience to another computer

Tags: x11

I have two computers: one is a very robust desktop with Ryzen 3600, 16GB of RAM, SSD storage and a RX 5700; the other is a weak laptop with a i5-4200u, 4GB of RAM and HDD storage. Most of the time I'm using my desktop I notice that I barely use a quarter of it's power, while while I use my laptop it always struggles to complete a few tasks and takes a lot of time to load programs. So my objective is to borrow the desktop's horsepower to the laptop, while I'm still using.

I've studied a little about Xserver and Xclient but I don't know if it fits my objective: let the laptop have a full desktop experience, as if it's running the OS itself (have a Desktop Environment up and running, open programs from the DE, close, maybe even play games in it).

I'm currently running Windows 10 on the desktop, but I have access to Linux Subsystems for Windows and I can also emulate Linux distros via VirtualBox; the laptop currently runs Linux Mint with Xfce.

Comment: DropBox or perhaps did you mean VirtualBox?

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant VirtualBox

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327532/how-to-remotely-log-in-with-full-graphical-desktop-over-x11/327534